# Why my simple filter in Jersey doesn't work?

Tags: java, http, jersey, servlet-filters

I try to use a simple filter with Jersey but without luck. My filter:

```
public class JerseyHelloFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest creq, ContainerResponse cresp) {
        System.out.println("JerseyHelloFilter : filter");
        return cresp;
    }
}
```

My web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Log Filter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.JerseyHelloFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Log Filter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My JSP page: `/my.page/index.jsp` 
My JAX-RS services: `/my.page/resources/*`

With above code I am expecting the `filter` method will be executed with every call to my site and return my page. But instead I get log from filter, and : `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found` when I try to access my index.jsp welcome file in the browser.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: That is true. My JAX-RS API is under `/my.page/resources/*` path. And my welcome file is just at `/my.page/index.jsp`. Thanks for hint I will check that yet..

Comment: You're welcome. Correcting the `url-pattern` for the filter should do the trick. Let us know if it worked.

Comment: Yesss! I put the `<url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>` and it works just like I need. But hmmm. I think I expected the Jersey gets control over my whole content.. Bad assumption.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. I'm moving my comment to an answer so it will benefit others that stumble across this later. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your JAX-RS mapping for serving requests through Jersey may be `/services/*`. So you are attempting to filter a request that Jersey is not configured to process. `/*` Will match a wider set of URLs.